# Error When trying to load win32/sound with Ruby

Tags: ruby, winapi, audio, rubygems, syntax-error

So I have been trying to figure this out and am not savvy enough with Ruby to quite understand the issue.

So I want to play sound from a ruby script. So after installing Ruby 2.2.1, I installed the most recent version of gems and then proceeded to download the win32-sound add on as follows

`gem install win32-sound`

After the installation was complete, I tried to run a simple script from my command line with the following code

```
require 'win32/sound'
include Win32

Sound.play('chimes.wav')
```

When I did this however, I ended up getting a slough of errors as follows

```
C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi_c (LoadError)
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.8-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:18:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.8-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/win32-sound-0.6.0/lib/win32/windows/functions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/win32-sound-0.6.0/lib/win32/sound.rb:1:in `require_relative'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/win32-sound-0.6.0/lib/win32/sound.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
from C:/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from player.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I am a bit confused. I thought I had install everything correctly, but now I am not so sure.